# Matlab and gnu-parallel

Tags: bash, matlab, unix, parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

I want to launch a number of parallel jobs in matlab exploiting the power of `gnu-parallel`.

In my folder I have the `test.m` file:

```
function test(a)
while 1
disp(a);
end
exit;
```

I'm used to launching multiple parallel session of `matlab` in this way:

```
for i in `seq 1 10`; do
  nohup matlab -singleCompThread -nodesktop -nosplash -r "test($i,43))" &
done
```

but what if I want to adapt this script to `gnu-parallel`? I've tried with:

```
parallel "matlab -nodisplay -nodesktop -nojvm -nosplash -r 'test({1})'" ::: 1 2 3 4
```

but this doesn't work at all. Using `gnu-parallel` for me should be of great help because it's able to balance computation and processes much better than my previous solution does.

Some ideas?

Comment: I would trade the 153 'followers' of `[hpc]` for 65 followers of `[gnu-parallel]`. Good luck.

Comment: Why don't you use the Matlab Parallel Computing Toolbox?

Comment: Because I don't have it installed. I should buy it but first I want to see if gnu-parallel can do a similar work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This ought to work (I do not have access to a matlab installation):

```
seq 1 10 | parallel 'matlab -singleCompThread -nodesktop -nosplash -r "test({},43))"'
```

Comment: @linello If this worked for you then you should consider accepting Ole's answer so your question doesn't continue floating around :-)